# Trigger event for specific plugin only

Tags: plugins, joomla

Is it possible to trigger a event for specific plugin?

I can load a specific plugin

$loaded = JPluginHelper::importPlugin('my_component', 'my_plugin_1');

But when I trigger an event, all the plugins that have that event are fired:

$results = JEventDispatcher::getInstance()->trigger('my_event');

I get the results not only of plugin1 but all the plugins that listen to that event.

$results = ['my_plugin_1_response', 'my_plugin_2_response'];

Is it possible to limit the plugins listening to the event to my_plugin_1_response only?

Please note that one possible solution would be to order the plugins and get the $results[0] as the result, but I'm not interested in this, I don't want that the other plugins are fired at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] and ask your Joomla questions there.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @VinayaK with your express permission I would like to ask that this page be migrated to Joomla Stack Exchange.  Please join that community and leave a comment below this one to confirm that you agree to the migration.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Yes will migrate to the Joomla community.

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange @Vin

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 4 boot the plugin and then call the function directly, like:

`$app->bootPlugin('my_plugin_1')->my_event();`